# Get the types (String, Boolean , Int, Nested etc ) of each field in the mapping with Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get the types of all my fields in my mapping with java API.

With this I can retrieve all the fields:

```
ClusterState cs = Client.admin().cluster().prepareState().execute().actionGet().getState();
IndexMetaData imd = cs.getMetaData().index(customerName);
MappingMetaData mmd = imd.mapping(type);
Map<String, Object> source = mmd.sourceAsMap();
for (String i : source.keySet()) {
        JSONObject jsonSource = null;
            try {
                jsonSource = new JSONObject(source.get(i).toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Iterator<?> iterator = jsonSource.keys();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                listFields.add(iterator.next().toString());
            }

        }
```

I looked for the methods in MappingMetaData but I got nothing that can give me the types of the field (e.g: string, float, int etc). I need to reatrive in the list of field only the ones which are core types (not with nested or inner object )

Comment: What do you get if you `System.out.println(i + " = " + source.get(i));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson's JsonNode:

```
MappingMetaData mmd = imd.mapping(type);
CompressedString source = mmd.source();
JsonNode mappingNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(source));

JsonNode propertiesNode = mappingNode.get("properties");
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> properties = propertiesNode.fields();
while (properties.hasNext()) {

  Entry<String, JsonNode> node = properties.next();
  String name = node.getKey();
  JsonNode valueNode = node.getValue();
  if (valueNode != null) {
    String type = valueNode.get("type").asText();//gives you the type
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's the solution !